Starting node from 2 different servers, peer ids on different chains
I have successfully started multiple nodes locally on one server but cannot get it working using 2 separate servers.
I keep getting:
Bootnode with peer id 12D3KooWKhzQdtN6L6Y2mLTnTzJ2GRzSFZ25rJrcBGxKDyzvmT2L is on a different chain (our genesis: 0x8ab5…ecce theirs: 0xff6f…6e7d)
This is what I'm doing:
Step 1
In Server #1:
Get the aura key for Node01
./target/release/node-template key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive
Get the gran key for Node01
./target/release/node-template key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Ed25519 "peace coin token eight left gather okay foot squirrel unit soda fame"
In Server #2:
Get the aura key for Node02
./target/release/node-template key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive
Get the gran key for Node02
./target/release/node-template key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Ed25519 "blur essay carpet charge fit shell capable album prison shallow shallow sand"
Step 2
In Server #1:
Add both Nodes to the customSpec.json file and generate raw file:
./target/release/node-template build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain local > customSpec.json
Step 3
In Server #1:
Store both keys to keystore: (I assume only the node needed for server #1 (Node01) should be stored here, but I've been adding both for no reason, but adding this here to not leave anything out)
// Node01

./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain customSpecRaw.json \
  --scheme Sr25519 \
  --suri "peace coin token eight left gather okay foot squirrel unit soda fame" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type aura

./target/release/node-template key insert \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain customSpecRaw.json \
  --scheme Ed25519 \
  --suri "peace coin token eight left gather okay foot squirrel unit soda fame" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type gran

// Node02

./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain customSpecRaw.json \
  --scheme Sr25519 \
  --suri "blur essay carpet charge fit shell capable album prison shallow shallow sand" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type aura

keystore grandpa
./target/release/node-template key insert \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain customSpecRaw.json \
  --scheme Ed25519 \
  --suri "blur essay carpet charge fit shell capable album prison shallow shallow sand" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type gran


In Server #2:
Store Node02 keys to keystore:
// Node02

./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain customSpecRaw.json \
  --scheme Sr25519 \
  --suri "blur essay carpet charge fit shell capable album prison shallow shallow sand" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type aura

keystore grandpa
./target/release/node-template key insert \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain customSpecRaw.json \
  --scheme Ed25519 \
  --suri "blur essay carpet charge fit shell capable album prison shallow shallow sand" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type gran


Step 4
Completely copy and paste both customSpec.json and customSpecRaw.json from Server #1 to Server #2
Step 5
From Server #1:
Start Node01 node with:
./target/release/node-template   --base-path /tmp/node01   --chain ./customSpecRaw.json   --port 30333   --rpc-port 9945  --rpc-cors all  --rpc-external  --validator --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods Unsafe   --name Node01   --password-interactive

From Server #2:
Start Node02
./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --rpc-port 9946 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name Node02 \
  --bootnodes /ip4/<ip>/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWKhzQdtN6L6Y2mLTnTzJ2GRzSFZ25rJrcBGxKDyzvmT2L \
  --password-interactive

Once I start the second node it will give:
Bootnode with peer id 12D3KooWKhzQdtN6L6Y2mLTnTzJ2GRzSFZ25rJrcBGxKDyzvmT2L is on a different chain (our genesis: 0x8ab5…ecce theirs: 0xff6f…6e7d)
And no peers are found.
I have read other posts similar to this and they all say to ensure the customSpec is identical, which I am making identical, at least I believe so by copy pasting.
Is there a thing You see I'm doing wrong?
It seems like it's reaching it but somehow not synced up. Doesn't seem like a firewall issue, I've opened the ports needed.
Is there some other way to ensure the the genesis is the same?

Looks like i got it working with "name": "My Custom Testnet",   "id": "testnet",   "chainType": "Development" and re storing the keypairs using this. I guess using Development is what changed this? going to test removing the id.
Although i do notice a lot of chains that are live, on their githubs they all use "Development" and not "Live" whats the difference?
